# Why is this dynamically assigned id using a loop only showing the first assignment? javascript, AJAX & JSTL

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jstl

Have a **Java based web application** with a page where a feed of posts is dynamically generated with the help of **JSTL**. The user can currently '*like*' any post in the feed but this has proved much more difficult to implement **using AJAX**. I know i'm really close here but can't quite figure out what's wrong.

**It works but only for the first item in the array..** So any like button that is pressed in the feed, only updates the first like button in the feed. **Why is it that the dynamically assigned div value (input name=likesDivCount) only registers the first assignment?**

index.jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${idFeedArray}" var="posts" varStatus="count">

...feed item (such as image, text etc..)...

<form id="likesform" action="../AddLike"  method="post" style="display:inline;">

  // the value of this input below is supposed to change...(i.e. #likesSize0,#likesSize1,#likesSize2)
   <input name="likesDivCount" value="#likesSize${count.index}" type="hidden">
   <input name="postUser" value="${userpost[count.index]}" type="hidden">


  // this button sends the AJAX request 
  <button style="padding-right: 0;"  type="submit" class="btn btn-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></button>

</form>

    // The span in the button below updates with the response from the AJAX
    <button style="padding-left: 0;" class="btn btn-link"><span id="likesSize${count.index}">${likesArraySize[count.index]}</span></button>


</c:forEach>


  <script>

       $(document).on("submit", "#likesform", function(event) {
            var $form = $(this);
            var likesDivCount = $("input[name=likesDivCount]").val();

           //this alert below is for testing, everytime the like button is pressed it displays '#likesSize0' and i need it to spit #likesSize1,#likesSize2,#likesSize3 etc...

            alert(likesDivCount); 

            $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serialize(), function(response) {      

            // only updates the first item :( (#likesSize0)
            $(likesDivCount).text(response);  


            });

            event.preventDefault(); // Important! Prevents submitting the form.
        });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have multiple forms with the same ID: '#likesform'. This is because your forms are generated in a loop.

I suggest you to remove the ID, replace it with a css class (or something else) and rewrite the JS to search for elements inside the target form, e.g.:

```
var $form = $(this);
var likesDivCount = $form.find("input[name=likesDivCount]").val();
```

Once you have valid html it will be easier to troubleshoot

Comment: Hmm but the form works perfectly fine, i can get the values dynamically for each post in the feed and i get the response i am looking for from the servlet. So it doesn't seem like having a dynamically named form will change anything. Or resolve this issue. Edit - I tested your solution just now and it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: You said: It works but only for the first item in the array.. So any like button that is pressed in the feed, only updates the first like button in the feed. I believe this is because of the multiple forms with the same IDs. As a general principle, you should never have replicated IDs in the same HTML document and the frameworks are not tested fir this. My suggestion is: get your html to be valid first, then if it doesn't work look into other stuff but you can exclude that it's because of the invalid html

Comment: ye my bad, played around with it some more, and using a unique name did fix it. Thanks!